Maximum of a functional on the boundary of the domain
I have a functional and want to find its maximum (and the maximazer function). My (limited) knowledge of variational calculus suggests to solve $\delta J = 0$. But the domain knowledge suggests that the maximum is located on the boundary of the domain of the functional, so the functional won't be stationary (is it correct?). The question is how to solve such problems.
Here is the functional:
$$J[p]=\int_0^T\left[1-p(t)\right]\exp\left(\int_0^t p(\tau)d\tau\right)dt$$
where $0 \leqslant p(t) \leqslant 1$ and $0 \leqslant t \leqslant T$
The maximizer most likely looks like this (found using an ansatz):
$$p(t)=\begin{cases}
1, & 0 \leqslant t \leqslant T-1 \\
0, & T-1 \lt t \leqslant T
\end{cases}$$
To be clear, I'm not even able to calculate the variation because of the nested integral. I'd appreciate any reference covering things more general then the regular functionals of the form $\int F(x,y,\dot y) dx$.
